# Unexpected output on initializing array by using both "Element-by-Element" & "Designated" techniques together

Tags: c, arrays, array-initialization

C99 provides a feature to initialize arrays by using both `element-by-element` & `designated` 
method together as:

```
int a[] = {2,1,[3] = 5,[5] = 9,6,[8] = 4};
```

On running the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a[] = {2,1,[3] = 5,[0] = 9,4,[6] = 25};
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
          printf("%d    ",a[i]);

   return 0;
 }
```

(**Note** that `Element 0` is initialized to `2` and then again initialised by designator `[0]`
to `9`)
I was expecting that `element 0`(which is `2`) will be replaced by `9`(as designator `[0] = 9`)
and hence o/p will become

```
   9    1   0   5   4   0   25
```

Unfortunately I was wrong as o/p came;

```
   9    4   0   5   0   0   25
```

Any explanation for unexpected o/p?

Comment: I think using `[0] = ...` resets the internal assignment counter back to 0, so the next element is assigned to `[1]` and so forth until another designated initializer is encountered.

Comment: would there ever be a reason to initialize an array _twice_ like this?

Comment: @hit; Because i have this question in my book.

Comment: @hacks what is the title of this book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of initializing an array with an initializer is basically:

1. set the index counter to 0, and initialize the entire array to 0s
2. go through the initializer elements from left to right
3. if the initializer element has a designated index, set the index counter to the designated index
4. store the initializer element value at the index given by the index counter
5. increment the index counter
6. go back to step 3 if there are any more initializer elements.

Comment: Good explanation.It seems like to be an `algorithm` for the above question.Very clear.

Answer (score 3):

Using designated initializers combined with element initializers implies positions based on the designated initializers.

So if you were to do:

```
int a[] = {2, 1, [3] = 5, 6};
```

The result ought to be:

```
2 1 0 5 6
```

Not:

```
2 1 0 6
```

Note that 6 occupies position 3 in the initializer, but its resulting position is implied by the preceding designated initializer (which uses position 3). The position following the one used by the designated initializer is 4, so that is where the 6 is placed.

Comment: It did't explain the reason behind the second o/p.

Comment: Actually, it does: the 4 comes after a designated initializer assigning position 0, so the 4 is placed in position 1.

Comment: I hit enter instead of shift-enter, my comment has been edited. My bad.